# When purchasing a robot, do I have to purchase an AI to operate it?

Tags: character-creation, equipment, eclipse-phase

When I buy a robot (buying gear at character creation), does it come with a basic AI that knows how to operate the 'bot, or do I have to purchase the AI separately?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[I asked](http://twitter.com/#!/MJKlaim/status/102076227023675394) Eclipse Phase authors on Twitter :

Response [Here](http://twitter.com/#!/EclipsePhase/status/102080241253629955)

> Nope, they come with a device AI (see the section on non-sapient AIs
>   for skill stats).

and [Here](http://twitter.com/#!/EclipsePhase/status/102080447181369344)

> What you can also do that is kind of a cool trick is either
>   teleoperate them or add a cyberbrain & use them as morphs.--jg

Comment: I don't know how to do this... - ok found it - done! :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say it comes with a basic type of AI that will give the robot the ability to perform normal tasks.  Anything more complex will require teaching from your part.  If you wanted a veteran AI in your robot, then yes, I would say that it require a cost.

Of course, you could always fork yourself and have the fork work/teach the robot then merge with your fork.  Or have a crippled fork that just stays inside the robot and does things for you -- no need for an AI then.

Of course, you referee may make the AI something special as part of the story.  If the robot is a legacy from before the Titans, then that opens plenty of interesting story ideas.  Maybe the AI in it is a fork of someone else.  Who?  Why?  ... Oh look plot ideas.

Comment: Can a delta fork run natively on a robot, or does a cyberbrain need to be installed?

Comment: It would depend on the robot I guess.  If it had diminished ego loader capability, then it would be able to. Of course, if it could take a whole fork, the robot would be called a morph. If it had a permanent link to the mesh, then the fork could live in the mesh. If it had neither, you should upgrade it so it does, you low tech punk! </point d'ironie>